# How to handle Web socket connected issue in android

Tags: android, websocket

I have used this library for the socket.

```
implementation ('com.github.nkzawa:socket.io-client:0.3.0',{
        exclude group:'org.json', module:'json'
    })
```

*I have found a number of solution for a WebSocket connections issue but still facing this issue.*

```
Fatal Exception: org.java_websocket.exceptions.WebsocketNotConnectedException
    org.java_websocket.WebSocketImpl.send (WebSocketImpl.java:566)
    org.java_websocket.WebSocketImpl.send (WebSocketImpl.java:543)
    org.java_websocket.client.WebSocketClient.send (WebSocketClient.java:171)
    com.github.nkzawa.engineio.client.transports.WebSocket$2.call (WebSocket.java:114)
    com.github.nkzawa.engineio.parser.Parser.encodePacket (Parser.java:63)
    com.github.nkzawa.engineio.parser.Parser.encodePacket (Parser.java:42)
    com.github.nkzawa.engineio.client.transports.WebSocket.write (WebSocket.java:110)
    com.github.nkzawa.engineio.client.Transport$3.run (Transport.java:98)
    com.github.nkzawa.thread.EventThread.exec (EventThread.java:50)
    com.github.nkzawa.engineio.client.Transport.send (Transport.java:94)
    com.github.nkzawa.engineio.client.Socket.flush (Socket.java:596)
    com.github.nkzawa.engineio.client.Socket.sendPacket (Socket.java:681)
    com.github.nkzawa.engineio.client.Socket.sendPacket (Socket.java:655)
    com.github.nkzawa.engineio.client.Socket.access$1500 (Socket.java:29)
    com.github.nkzawa.engineio.client.Socket$17.run (Socket.java:565)
    com.github.nkzawa.thread.EventThread.exec (EventThread.java:50)
    com.github.nkzawa.engineio.client.Socket.ping (Socket.java:562)
    com.github.nkzawa.engineio.client.Socket$16$1.run (Socket.java:550)
    com.github.nkzawa.thread.EventThread$2.run (EventThread.java:75)
```

Comment: You can use okhttp's websocket

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-java

```
 OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
                    @Override
                    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                        Request request = chain.request();
                        Request.Builder builder = request.newBuilder();
                        builder.header("Accept", "application/json")
                        return chain.proceed(builder.build());
                    }
                })
                .addInterceptor(new com.ihsanbal.logging.LoggingInterceptor.Builder()
                        .loggable(true)
                        .setLevel(Level.BASIC)
                        .log(Platform.INFO)
                        .request("Request")
                        .response("Response")
                        .build());

        okhttp3.OkHttpClient okHttpClient = httpClient.build();

        IO.Options opts = new IO.Options();
        opts.forceNew = true;
        opts.callFactory = okHttpClient;
        opts.webSocketFactory = okHttpClient;

        if (mSocket == null || isClosed) {
            io.socket.client.Socket mSocket = IO.socket("http://yorurl.com", mOptions);
        }

        mSocket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT, args -> {
            if (!isConnected) {
                Log.i(TAG, "onSocketConnected");
                isConnected = true;
                isClosed = false;
            }
        });
        mSocket.on(Socket.EVENT_DISCONNECT, args -> {
            Log.i(TAG, "onDisconnected");
            isConnected = false;
        });

        mSocket.on(Socket.EVENT_ERROR, args -> {

            Log.i(TAG, "onConnectError");
            isConnected = false;
        });

        mSocket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT_ERROR, args -> {

            Log.i(TAG, "onConnectError");
            isConnected = false;
        });

        mSocket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT, args -> {

            Log.i(TAG, "onConnectTIMEOUT");
            isConnected = false;
        });

        if (!mSocket.connected() && !isConnected) {
            mSocket.connect();
        }
```